# Recover deleted files in spyder 4

Tags: python-3.x, ide, spyder, recovery, data-recovery

I am unable to recover files and folders deleted from spyder 4.

And the deleted files are not in the trash also. Anyone help me here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) I'm sorry but files deleted through our Files or Project panes are permanently deleted from your hard drive. That's why we show a warning message about that before proceeding.

We understand this is a serious problem and we'll try to fix it in Spyder 5. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Does this situation persist even if the IDE gets crashed. Coz in my editor other folders  were actually deleted.

Comment: Oh my god, I accidentally delete the main folder and there's no way to recover, I won't use this editor again